# Finding sum of values of keys having duplicates values in php

Tags: php

I'm not able to find a solution for the given scenario where I have a multidimensional array in which I have to find the sum of the values of the arrays that have same ID.

**demo.php**

```
$array = array("1"=>array("id"=>"1", "total"=>"100"),
                "2"=>array("id"=>"2", "total"=>"300"),
                "3"=>array("id"=>"3", "total"=>"400"),
                 "4"=>array("id"=>"4", "total"=>"500"),
                 "5"=>array("id"=>"1", "total"=>"560"));
```

I want to get the sum of the total of all the duplicates IDs e.g 1 is the ID and the sum of the total would be 100 + 560 = 650.

Comment: Just loop through it with a foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to summarize the array into an associative array.

```
$array = //....

$result = array_reduce( $array, function( $c, $v ){

    if ( !isset( $c[ $v["id"] ] ) ) $c[ $v["id"] ] = 0;
    $c[ $v["id"] ] += $v["total"];

    return $c;
}, array() );
```

`$result` will be:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 660
    [2] => 300
    [3] => 400
    [4] => 500
)
```

---

**UPDATE**

Add another `reduce` to group the array first. The second `reduce` is to only include the array elements with more than one count.

```
$array = //....
$group = array_reduce( $array, function( $c, $v ){
    if ( !isset( $c[ $v["id"] ] ) ) $c[ $v["id"] ] = [ "count" => 0, "total" => 0, "id" => $v["id"] ];
    $c[ $v["id"] ]["count"] += 1;
    $c[ $v["id"] ]["total"] += $v["total"];
    return $c;
}, array() ); 

$result = array_reduce( $group, function( $c, $v ){
    if ( $v["count"] > 1 ) $c[ $v["id"] ] = $v["total"];
    return $c;
}, array() );
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 660
)
```

Comment: result array should not contain other elements . it should contain only the  sum of the values of the duplicate id's

Answer (score 2):

Another take while using a `foreach`:

```
$array = array("1"=>array("id"=>"1", "total"=>"100"),
            "2"=>array("id"=>"2", "total"=>"300"),
            "3"=>array("id"=>"3", "total"=>"400"),
             "4"=>array("id"=>"4", "total"=>"500"),
             "5"=>array("id"=>"1", "total"=>"560"));

$total = [];

foreach ($array as $sub) {
    $total[$sub['id']] = isset($total[$sub['id']]) ? $total[$sub['id']] += $sub['total'] : $total[$sub['id']] = $sub['total'];
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => 660
    [2] => 300
    [3] => 400
    [4] => 500
)
```

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/CorruptAuthenticMeasurements)

**Reading Material**

[Ternary Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple foreach loop to get the expected result

```
<?php
// Your code here!
$array = array("1"=>array("id"=>"1", "total"=>"100"),
                "2"=>array("id"=>"2", "total"=>"300"),
                "3"=>array("id"=>"3", "total"=>"400"),
                 "4"=>array("id"=>"4", "total"=>"500"),
                 "5"=>array("id"=>"1", "total"=>"560"));
$issetArray = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($issetArray[$value['id']]))
    {
        $issetArray[$value['id']]['total'] += $value['total'];
    }
    else
    {
        $issetArray[$value['id']] = array();
        $issetArray[$value['id']] = $value;
    }
}

$result = array();
foreach ($issetArray as $value) {
    array_push($result, $value);
}

print_r($result);
?>
```

Example: https://paiza.io/projects/Fnay-hbk4Cuf_-rMTL5AFA

Comment: @Script47 You can suggest some point. I'm using the same code in my day by day coding. It would be helpful for me to reduce complicated code. Thanks

Comment: Great, Just seen your example from the next time I'll keep the same in mind. Thanks to you learned a new way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the external class [tableArray](https://github.com/jspit-de/tableArray) and you want to preserve the structure of the input array try this:

```
$array = array("1"=>array("id"=>"1", "total"=>"100"),
                "2"=>array("id"=>"2", "total"=>"300"),
                "3"=>array("id"=>"3", "total"=>"400"),
                 "4"=>array("id"=>"4", "total"=>"500"),
                 "5"=>array("id"=>"1", "total"=>"560"));

$newData = tableArray::create($array)
  ->filterGroupSum('total',['id'])
  ->fetchAll()
;
```

$newData:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => "1",
    'total' => 660,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => "2",
    'total' => 300,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => "3",
    'total' => 400,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => "4",
    'total' => 500,
  ),
)
```